# Stop Specific Error Types Showing In Console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Is there any way that one can stop the console listing a specific error?

I ask, as since Chrome 63 it displays an error "Found 2 elements with non-unique id" many times in the console, and can make it more difficult to find any errors for any other issues that I am debugging.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0):

You can type `-<text>` in the **Filter** text box to filter out the messages that contain `<text>`.

In the screenshot below, the message that logged out `two` to the Console is hidden, because the **Filter** text box is set to `-two`.

[image: negative filter]